# Highlighted content - how to filter by custom column?

Tags: column, kql, highlighted-content-web-part

We use SharePoint as a wiki. So we create modern pages in the standard library and in a newly added column we specify that it is a wiki page. The views are filtered accordingly so that only wiki pages are displayed.

We have one parent site and 4 sub sites. The **subwebsites contain the wiki pages** (i.e. the **modern pages** with the **custom property or column "Wiki page" = "Yes"**). On the start page, I would like to display only the changes to these wiki pages which are located in the libraries on the subwebsites and have the column value **"Wiki page" = "Yes"**. I know that I can create queries with **KQL**. FileType, Title etc. all these things I can access and use in queries.

So my question is: **How can I access my newly added custom column and use it in my queries?**